# how do i set notifications for all dates generated in a for loop

Tags: java, android

```
    String date = "28/04/2018";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PondDaily.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    int maxDay = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    for (int co = 0; co < maxDay; co++) {
        System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 21);

    }
```

this is my code am generating all dates 21 days after the start date
thanks

Comment: Question is unclear right now you might consider editing it with proper problem . If you want to set future notifications pls make use of [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

Comment: What do you mean by "set a notification"?  What kind of notification are you talking about?  Notification to who or what?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: i need to add notifications or reminder to the dates that will be generated from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainActivity.class

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          scheduleNotification(getNotification("text to be displayed"), calendar);


        }


    private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, Calendar calendar) {

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationNotify.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationNotify .NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
                notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationNotify .NOTIFICATION, notification);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }

            private Notification getNotification(String content) {
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
                builder.setContentText(content);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                return builder.build();
            }
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class NotificationNotify extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

Android Mainfest

```
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationNotify " />
```